# Java Generics and containers of mixed types

Tags: java, generics

I have a question about using mixed generic types in a container.

I have something like this:

```
interface Processor<T> {

    T process(T value);
}

class StringProcessor implements Processor<String> {

    String process(String value);
}
```

Then I have another parameterized class or interface that uses the processor. And I want to ensure that the processor that we set to the Element can deal with elements of this type (T)

```
 class Element<T> {

      <U> void setProcessor(U extends Processor<? extends T> processor);
 }
```

All of this works fine. My issue comes when I have to put my elements in a container. This container can contain elements of different types (`Element<String>`, `Element<Integer>`, ... ). When I get the elements out of the container I cannot assign a new calcultor to the element, because using ? makes me lose the typing.

```
 List<Element<?>> container = new ArrayList<Element<?>>();
 Element<String> strElement =new Element<String>();
 strElement.setProcessor(new StringProcessor());
 Element<Integer> intElement =new Element<Integer>();
 intElement.setProcessor(new IntegerProcessor());

 container.add(strElement);
 container.add(intElement);
```

But:

```
 Element<?> e = container.get(0);
 e.setProcessor(new StringProcessor());   // This does not compile because the the      compiler is expecting a processor of type U extends Processor<#1of?> and not a StringProcessor.
```

This works with Rawtypes but do you think there is a way to manage this cleanly with generics?

I have read the pattern from "Effective Java", but when I am reading elements from my container I can't predict what the return type will be.

The only fix I have found so far is making Element not generic, but by doing so I am losing the type safety.

Any idea welcome?

Regards

Gilles

Comment: Your `Element` class doesn't compile. Can you provide a valid implementation?

Comment: You cannot as you currently have it. The usual pattern is to have a `boolean canProcess(Object o)` method on the `Processor`. Then check this method and force a cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Element<?> e = container.get(0);` could in fact result in an `Element` for any type of `Processor` it is not possible to set that field in it for any particular type. Once you mix different types together there is no way to get that information back, in a statically typed way.

What you can to is to implement some kind of runtime check, as Boris suggests. To do this the objects must maintain information at runtime about which types they can handle.  A number of variants would be possible. For example:

```
class Element<T> {
    public Class<T> elementType;

    <U extends Processor<? extends T>> void setProcessor(U processor) {}

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <E> Element<E> getTyped(Class<E> type) {
        if (type == elementType) return (Element<E>) this;
        else return null;
    }
}

Element<?> e = new Element<String>();
Element<String> es = e.getTyped(String.class);
if (es != null) es.setProcessor(new StringProcessor());
```

You get an unchecked warning for the cast in `getTyped` but it is safe to suppress it because you check that the types are matching at runtime.

**EDIT: About changing `elementType`**

When the `Element` is created it probably has a concrete type and you can set `elementType` field without a problem.

Changing `elementType` on an existing `Element` is problematic because there might exist references to it with the old type. For example, if you have a `Element<Sting>` reference to an object, and change `elementType` to `Integer` in some other part of the code, then you get a `ClassCastException` when you use the first reference even if there was no casts in that part of the code. This is what the "Unchecked cast" compilation warning is telling you about.

If you want to do it anyway you can write a method similar to `getTyped`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <E> Element<E> getTypedAndClear(Class<E> type) {
    elementType = null;
    return (Element<E>) this;
}
```

Afterwards you can set `elementType` to the class object of the type `E`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do you set the elementType in Element<T>

Comment: I edited my answer and added some text about that. Since you are new to this site I also want to remind you to upvote the answer if you find it useful and accept it if it solves your problem.

Comment: Done thanks a lot. I used a mix of Boris solution (added a method on Processor) and yours (added a type to Element so that I can validate the type safety). Thanks again

Comment: @Gilles: Great! It might also be useful to store a `Class<T>` in the processor to be able to check if a processor and an element match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Element<String> e = container.get(0); // chnages ? to Stirng
e.setProcessor(new StringProcessor());
```